# Is there a way to do conditional select statements in SQLite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to create an app in which the user has the option to query the database by entering information into one of two entry boxes. I want to be able to use a single select statement and conditionally query the database based on what box the user enter their information into. I currently am trying to use a CASE clause, but I believe that it is running into an error when I try to include a WHERE clause in the THEN argument. Here is what I am currently working with:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')

    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("""
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN :var1 <> '' THEN * WHERE column1 = :var1
            ELSE * WHERE column2 LIKE '%'||var2||'%' 
        FROM table_name
        """,
        
        {
            'var1': entrybox1.get(),
            'var2': entrybox2.get()
        })
```

When I run this through my compiler I get a syntax error around where the WHERE clause begins in the THEN line. The dictionary keys are representative of the different text fields where I get user inputs. Any suggestions on what I could do here to fix this issue or a more efficient method of solving the question that I am trying to answer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just switch it in Python…!? `if entrybox1.get(): c.execute('SELECT * WHERE ...') else: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `CASE` expression to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE CASE 
  WHEN :var1 <> '' THEN column1 = :var1
  ELSE column2 LIKE '%' || :var2 || '%' 
END
```

The result of the `CASE` expression is a Boolean value like `column1 = :var1` or `column2 LIKE '%' || :var2 || '%'`, so it is suitable at the WHERE clause.

Comment: just curiosity, is it allowed to use a `case when` which returns a comparison? I have never seen that before... As far as I know, the `case when` performs a comparison and returns a value, not another comparison, but maybe in sqlite/python it's different...

Comment: @JaimeDrq a CASE expression returns 1 value. If this value is `column1 = :var1` this  is a Boolean value 0 or 1.

Comment: Can you please make an example in db<>fiddle? I am quite curious about how writting that query, but I totally trust you!

Comment: @JaimeDrq no, at the moment I can't. If you want you can try it with your own sample data.

Comment: @forpas, indeed I did it, and it just work in sqlite, not in sql server and neither in Oracle... that's why I haven't seen that before (I haven't ever worked with sqlite). But thanks, is good to learn something new eveyday, I upvote your answer.